# Grouping amounts of data together and creating a on-the-fly amt column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database like this:

```
id - join_id - bool
1 - 32 - 1
2 - 32 - 0
3 - 32 - 1
4 - 32 - 1
```

I would like to query this:

```
join_id - bool (- amount)
32 - 1 - 3 (aka there are 3 instances where the join_id and bool are 32 and 1);
32 - 0 - 1 (aka there is 1 instances where the join_id and bool are 32 and 0);
```

Any key  words, or names would really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for I think:

```
SELECT join_id, bool, COUNT(id) AS amount FROM mytable GROUP BY join_id,bool
```

Comment: Do you know how to set a default value for a column generated with `AS`?

Comment: 'AS' just give the column an alias, meaning it will appear, in this case, as 'amount', rather than being called 'COUNT(id)'. The default value for each row depends entirely on the statement for that column. In this case I would say the 'default' is 0..